# Can hashCode() and == diverge without overriding hashCode

Tags: java

Given java [Object#hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) documentation snapshot :

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (The
>   hashCode may or may not be implemented as some function of an object's
>   memory address at some point in time.)

How would we make this method return true **without overriding** the `hashCode()` method ?

```
boolean challenge(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1 == o2 && o1.hashCode() != o2.hashCode();
}
```

Stated otherwise, make this method return true :

```
boolean makeMeReturnTrue(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1 == o2 && System.identityHashCode(o1) != System.identityHashCode(o2);
}
```

Comment: As long as the implementation of `hashCode`  is valid, this is not possible. The contract specifies that `hashCode` **must** have the same logic than `equals`. And `equals` **must** be **reflexive**, i.e. it must always be `true` on the same object. The opposite case is possible though: `o1 != o2 && o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

If `o1 == o2`, then `o1.hashCode()` is certain to return the same value as `o2.hashCode()`, which will make the expression return `false`.

One of the properties of `hashCode()` is consistency, meaning that within the same program, the result of `hashCode()` on the same object should not change (and changing the return value is the only way to make the expression return `true` - but you can't get `Object.equals` to return incosistent values, so you would be forced to override `hashCode` to break the contract for yourself).

Answer (score 3):

```
return o1 == o2 && o1.hashCode() != o2.hashCode();
```

The expression `o1 == o2` tests o1 and o2 to see if they refer to the same object. Not two objects that compare equally, but the actual same object. So `o1 == o2` will only be true if `o1` and `o2` refer to the same object.

Given that o1 and o2 must be the same object, the only way for `o1.hashCode() != o2.hashCode()` to be true would be if the relevant `hashCode()` method returned a different value each time it was called. For example, the expression could be true if `hashCode()` returned a random value each time it was called. That violates the expectation for `hashCode()`, but you could certainly write a non-conformant `hashCode()` method if you wanted to.

Comment: `hashCode` returns an int, not a string, and the question says "without overriding hashCode".

Answer (score 0):

Well, its going to depend on actual implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals()` for the final Objects that get passed in. It looks like your class has an implementation where equality stands for "we contain the same data", but you seem to be hoping that the hash code implementation is based on the memory address or some other "unique to this instantiation" identifier so that something may not challenge itself.

You could always manage that identifier yourself, which would be safest (since the underlying implementation of `hashCode()` could change on a default version of a common data structure during a major Java version update for example), but it might be overkill.

Answer (score -2):

Just download openJDK and modify the code as per your requirement. It'll work. But it'll work only in your own custom JDK that you have created by modifying OpenJDK. Use your custom JDK where you need to deploy your application.